# Django multiple inline doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have a django model like this.

**model.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Occurrence(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    occurrence = models.ForeignKey(Occurrence)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

**admin.py**

```
class TimeSlotInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = TimeSlot
    extra = 1

class OccurrenceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Occurrence
    inlines = [TimeSlotInline,]
    extra = 2

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OccurrenceInline,]

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
admin.site.register(Location)
```

I want to display all fields in one page in admin page.(When adding new records.)
Multiple inline doesn't work.(Only first inline comes.)
Is there any other way to do this ?

Update: Can I do this by modifying admin.py file. Can I add a customized form to inlines of admin.py?

Comment: Any help? I still couldn't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't have nested inlines (inlines within inlines)in the Django admin at the moment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025)

**EDIT**

[Nested inlines in the Django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681258/nested-inlines-in-the-django-admin)

Comment: Thanks pastylegs, I saw it before, but I couldnt apply that patch to django 1.3. Can I overcome this issue by adding a form (by modiying administration panel)? Or do you have any solution either?

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be:

```
class OccurrenceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Occurrence
    extra = 2

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OccurrenceInline, TimeSlotInline,]
```