# 3 Tiered Ordering Application using Django Admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested inlines in the Django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681258/nested-inlines-in-the-django-admin)

I'm developing an application for a catering company, using Python, Django and PostgreSQL. I have tried to use the Django Admin module as a way to add orders. I want to be able to do everything on one page. I am starting to believe it may not be possible.
Do not worry, only office staff will be using this part of the software, not the general public.

Our pricing structure works on the number of items per person, multiplied by the people being catered for.

Here is an example:

---

**Order for "Fake Company":**

- Morning Tea of 2 items at $8.00 x 10ppl:     #This is what we call a deal, items have no price.

  - Gluten Free Biscuits x1
  - Sausage Roll  x10
  - Biscuits         x9
- Lunch of 3 items at $10.00 x 10ppl:

  - Sausage Roll  x5
  - Sushi         x5
  - Sandwich      x10
  - Sweet Platter x10

---

**Total: $180**

---

The way each order is structured in the database is like this:
-COMPANY
  -SALE (One-TO-One relationship with COMPANY)
    -DEAL_INSTANCE (One-To-One relationship with both SALE and a DEAL)
      -ITEM (Many-TO-Many relationship with DEAL_INSTANCE through a join table, as an item quantity
                  field is required)

I have managed to get everything but adding items to a DEAL_INSTANCE, on one page. Due to Django Admin not really liking Many-To-Many Relationships defined with the 'through' attribute.

Here is a link to a screenshot of what I already have, just to clarify things (just copy image location to view fullsize): [image: What I have so far.]

So in closing, I ask is it possible to have this whole process on one page using Django Admin?
If not, what's the best way to go about it using Django and should I change the layout of my database?

Thanks in advance, I know this is a bit of an odd situation to get your head around.
I am a Django newbie, but proficient in Python; so you may need to hold my hand when it comes to Django.

Answer (score 0):

No, nested inlines are not available in the admin.

[#9025 Nested Inline Support in Admin](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025)

The admin interface is not really designed to be anything other than a generic interface, and should not be used for access to anyone but the most trusted of users.

It's not that difficult to do nested inlines in a non-admin django view: googling "django nested inlines" reveals a handful of solutions.

Comment: I know nested inlines aren't natively available in the admin interface, I thought there might be some hackish way to achieve it. I was really trying to avoid doing that much extra work, but I think making my own views for this part of the app might be the best option. I just love all the magic the admin interface performs on my behalf.

Comment: Any advice on how to go about this would be much appreciated, as inline forms for views are not well documented.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22586283/554807