# Managing list of lists in django admin

Tags: django

I am writing a django application, that stores and displays working hours of employees.

The problem is, that for example pediatrists have 2 types of working hours - separate for sick children and healthy ones.

So I thought, it would be cool, to use HTML table to display the hours for each employee. My idea was to have a "ListField" representing each row of table, with ForeignKey to employee. That way, admin could create lists like:

```
['', 'Sick Children', 'Healthy Children'],
['Monday', '8-12', '12-14'],
['Friday', '12-15']
```

And it would appear on website, as an HTML table, that would look pretty nice.

The thing is, I would love it to look easy and intuitive for an admin of website. So I would love to keep the table rows as inline of employee in admin panel.
So, I have created models:

```
class TableRow(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)

class TableCell(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    row = models.ForeignKey(TableRow)
```

And tried stuff like:

```
class TableCellInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TableCell

class TableRowInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TableRow

class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TableRowInline]

admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
admin.site.register(TableRow, TableRowAdmin)
```

Which doesn't work (as I expected, but didn't hurt to try). Admin panel shows an option to add table row, when adding/editing employee, but doesn't show any option to add any cell to the row.

Is there any way to allow adding the rows while editing/adding employee? Or maybe a totally different way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is commonly referred to as nested inlines. Unfortunately, I'm afraid this is still not supported by the admin. See the following resources for more information.

[Nested inlines in the Django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3681258/687488)

[#9025 assigned New feature: Nested Inline Support in Admin](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025)