# How to open heirarchy children of specific foreignKey in Django?

Tags: python, django, admin

I am new to Django and trying to make an educational App. I have a Model heirarchy as Subject>Level>Chapter>Topic>Article

I want to add Articles on specific Topic in a Specific Chapter of a specific Level in a Subject? How is it possible to open children of specific ForeignKey? E.g. I want this is admin panel, If I click on a subject I get Children Levels and then Children Chapters and so on...

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Level(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Level, Subject, Article, Chapter, Topic

admin.site.register(Level)
admin.site.register(Subject)
admin.site.register(Article)
admin.site.register(Chapter)
admin.site.register(Topic)
```

Comment: You will need to use nested inlines: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681258/nested-inlines-in-the-django-admin

Comment: Thanks but its make things more complex..

Comment: It is not really complex to use this. Try to get used to implement thrid party modules in django - it will make your live easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using-

https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin
The admin would look something like-

```
class SubjectInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Subject
    extra = 1


class LevelInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    inlines = [SubjectInline]
    model = Level
    extra = 1


class ChapterInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    inlines = [LevelInline]
    model = Chapter
    extra = 1

class TopicInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    inlines = [ChapterInline]
    model = Topic
    extra = 1

class ArticleAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TopicInline]
    model = Article
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: Copy pasted from the link mentioned by @ger.s.brett